# c# ushort uint16 which type to choose

Tags: c#, casting, typeconverter, uint16, ushort

I can't understand why we can have `ushort` and `uint16`… 2 bytes for both. But a problem if I want to use Convert. If I remember well it's `ushort.parse(stringtype)` while `convert.touint16` needs an object.

I searched but can't find why… In the past I used the ushort type, but I begin to think because I need this time to convert object to ushort it's not a good idead to use ushort. I find it's a bit strange to convert to string then to convert to ushort… or to convert to uint16 then to cast to ushort. Perhaps I missed something?

It's not a crucial point but I would like to know.

Comment: C#'s `ushort` is just an alias for .Net's `System.UInt16`. You should be able to use `Convert.ToUInt16()` and `ushort.Parse()` without having to do any casting between the two.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot !!